# Racket number->string conversion issue

Tags: string, numbers, decimal, racket

When I write in DrRacket:

```
(number->string (/ 3 2))
```

I get

```
"3/2"
```

How can I get `"1.5"` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`~r`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html?q=~r#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fformat..rkt%29._~7er%29%29):

```
(~r (/ 3 2))
=> "1.5"
(~r (/ 2 2))
=> "1"
```

Comment: Thanks. However if I do (number->string (exact->inexact (/ 2 2))) I get "1.0". In this case I want just "1"

Comment: @David here you go :)

Comment: This means using (require racket/format) package. Do you know any other way without using a specific package?

Comment: No, you don't need to use that package, `~r` is included in `#lang racket`. Another alternative would be to use `format`, but that requires `srfi/48`.